# in R, how to separate start, middle, and of end of string when length of string is variable?

Tags: r, string, indexing

For example I have this,

```
Full Name
1 Fred Peters 
2 Fred Lukas Peters
3 Fred Lukas James Peters
4 Fred Lukas of James Peters
```

But want to have,

```
First     Middle          Last
1 Fred                      Peters
2 Fred      Lukas           Peters
3 Fred      Lukas James     Peters
4 Fred      Lukas of James  Peters
5 Michael                   Smith
```

I know how to separate a string into multiple columns using
`separate(Full Name, c("First","Middle","Last"), " ")`

but am confused on how to tell R that the last word of the string should always be in the last column, and everything between First and Last should be between.

Comment: Ignore the 5th observation in the second data frame

Answer (score 1):

We could use `extract`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(`Full Name` = str_replace(`Full Name`, 
     '^(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)$', "\\1 NA \\2")) %>%
     extract(`Full Name`, into = c("First","Middle","Last"), 
          "^(\\S+)\\s+(.*)?\\s+(\\S+)$", convert = TRUE)
```

-output

```
   First         Middle   Last
1  Fred             NA Peters
2  Fred          Lukas Peters
3  Fred    Lukas James Peters
4  Fred Lukas of James Peters
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`Full Name` = c("Fred Peters", "Fred Lukas Peters", 
"Fred Lukas James Peters", "Fred Lukas of James Peters")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, however, it got rid of every observation that didn't have a middle name. How can I solve this?